# find duplicate objects whose one of the key-vlaue pair is same in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. Every object has a `name` key, I want to return an array of objects which contain same `name` value objects in an array against a key.
Thank you.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 20,
  },
  {
    name: "Brad",
    age: 24,
  },
  ,
  {
    name: "Will",
    age: 20,
  },
  ,
  {
    name: "Alex",
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    name: "Taylor",
    age: 21,
  },
];
```

**Expected output:**

```js
[
  {
    1: [
      {
        name: "John",
        age: 20,
      },
      {
        name: "Will",
        age: 20,
      },
    ],
    2: [
      {
        name: "Brad",
        age: 24,
      },
      {
        name: "Taylor",
        age: 24,
      },
    ],
    3: [
      {
        name: "Alex",
        age: 25,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: expected has a group by age?

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

```js
 result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.age] = r[a.age] || [];
    r[a.age].push(a);
    return r;
  }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```